# VS Graphics Diagnostic Tools and IDXGIFactory::EnumAdapters()

Tags: directx11, visual-studio

I have the following constructor for my main application class where i enumerate all adapters, that looks something like this:

```
CApplication::CApplication() 
{
    IDXGIFactory* factory;
    CreateDXGIFactory(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&factory));

    IDXGIAdapter* adapter;
    unsigned adapterIndex = 0;
    while (factory->EnumAdapters(adapterIndex, &adapter) != DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND)
    {
        mAdapters.push_back(adapter);
        ++adapterIndex;
    }

    ReleaseCOM(factory);
    //...
    HRESULT hr = D3D11CreateDevice(
        mAdapters[adapterIndexToUse],
        mDriverType, nullptr,
        createDeviceFlags,
        nullptr, 0, D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
        &md3d11Device, &mFeatureLevel, &md3d11ImmediateContext);
}
```

I have Intel HD Graphics 4000 as  primary display adapter and NVIDIA GeForce GT 620M as "back-up" display adapter which do all the heavy work.(i.e. rendering in games)

I want to use Visual Studio 2013 Graphics Diagnostic tools while using NVIDIA GPU, and since NVIDIA GPU is secondary adapter, this corresponds to setting `adapterIndexToUse=1`.
Problem is that while enumerating adapters only Indel GPU gets enumerated. 

That is, call to `factory->EnumAdapter(adapterIndex, &adapter)` returns `DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND` if `adapterIndex > 0` while using Visual Studio Graphics Diagnostic tools and so my `mAdapters` class attribute which is `std::vector<IDXGIAdapter*>` have size 1 causing out of bounds exception when we try to create the Device with `adapterIndexToUse` specified as 1 (So i use my secondary NVIDIA GPU).

Only cause of this error i have come to think of is that Graphics Diagnostic tools is only supported on primary display adapter, but i don't see why that would be the case.

Comment: One issue is likely that you are using DXGI 1.0 which was for Direct3D 10. You might get some appcompat behavior that way. Try using: ``IDXGIFactory1* factory; HRESULT hr = CreateDXGIFactory1(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory1), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&factory));``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The main issue the OP is hitting is that VS Graphics Diagnostics does not support DirectX 10/DXGI 1.0 applications**.

For DirectX 10 on Windows Vista, you used `CreateDXGIFactory` and created a `IDXGIFactory` class instance. This is "DXGI 1.0".

For DirectX 11, you should use `CreateDXGIFactory1` and `IDXGIFactory1` which is DXGI 1.1.

It is also important not to mix different versions of DXGI in the same application. If you are explicitly creating a DXGI factory and enumerating the devices, then as long as you use `CreateDXGIFactory1` you should be fine.

If, however, you are creating the 'default' device and then need to get the DXGI factory that was used to create it, you should use this trick instead:

```
IDXGIFactory1* dxgiFactory = nullptr;
{
    IDXGIDevice* dxgiDevice = nullptr;
    hr = pDevice->QueryInterface( __uuidof( IDXGIDevice ), reinterpret_cast<void**>( &dxgiDevice ) );
    if ( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
    {
        IDXGIAdapter* adapter = nullptr;
        hr = dxgiDevice->GetAdapter( &adapter );
        if ( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
        {
            hr = adapter->GetParent( __uuidof( IDXGIFactory1 ),
                reinterpret_cast<void**>( &dxgiFactory ) );
            if (FAILED(hr)) dxgiFactory = nullptr;
            adapter->Release();
        }
        dxgiDevice->Release();
    }
}
```

Or a bit more succinctly using `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr`

```
ComPtr<IDXGIFactory1> dxgiFactory;
{
    ComPtr<IDXGIDevice1> dxgiDevice;
    HRESULT hr = m_d3dDevice.As(&dxgiDevice);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Identify the physical adapter (GPU or card) this device is running on.
        ComPtr<IDXGIAdapter> dxgiAdapter;
        hr = dxgiDevice->GetAdapter(dxgiAdapter.GetAddressOf());
        if ( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
        {
            // And obtain the factory object that created it.
            hr = dxgiAdapter->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory1), &dxgiFactory));
            if (FAILED(hr)) dxgiFactory = nullptr;
        }
   }
}
```

See [Anatomy of Direct3D 11 Create Device](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2014/02/05/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device.aspx) and [DirectX Graphics Infrastructure (DXGI): Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee417025.aspx)